# PowerShell match array to two wildcard variables

Tags: arrays, powershell, match

Afternoon, I'm working on some code to verify that an array contains two specific file extensions and am running into a roadblock on getting that done.

I'm using a Windows Form OpenFileDialog window and returning the value as `$Files = $OpenFileDialog.FileNames` What I want to do is verify that the files selected (array) contains a (for testing purposes) a `.txt` and a `.log` before continuing. I've tried messing with `-Contains` but that works on exact matches and I've kind of played with regex but that is still confusing to me.

What I'm trying to check for is that there wasn't two `.txt` or `.log` files selected, just one of each, so I don't think a loop will work as that(maybe it will, my brain doesn't want to work anymore today)

Comment: If you're using `OpenFileDialog`, instead of comparing, why not prevent any other extension from being available? This class has a filter already

Comment: I have it filtered to show what I want already, but I want them to select multiple files at once, but don't want them to select two of the same extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`GetExtension` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=net-7.0) to get the extension and a calculated expression with `Group-Object`, then filter where the groups have a count greater than `1` and if you have any result out of that then you can be sure the user selected 2 or more files with the same extension.

Example:

```
$result = @(
    'foo.txt'
    'bar.log'
    'baz.txt'
) | Group-Object { [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_) } |
    Where-Object Count -GT 1

if ($result) {
    # here is for the user selected 2 or more files with the same extension
}
```

Comment: It's been a hot minute but as always, appreciate the assistance! worked like a charm